# how do you tidy and combine two data frames with slightly different primary keys?

Tags: r, tidyr

stream table

| experiment | protocol | test | stream_size | metric | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tcp | stream | 64 | throughput Gbps | 10 |
| 1 | tcp | stream | 64 | cpu utilization | .5 |
| 2 | tcp | stream | 64 | throughput Gbps | 40 |
| 2 | tcp | stream | 64 | cpu utilization | .9 |
| 3 | udp | stream | 64 | throughput Gbps | 20 |
| 3 | udp | stream | 64 | cpu utilization | .5 |
| 4 | udp | stream | 64 | throughput Gbps | 60 |
| 4 | udp | stream | 64 | cpu utilization | .8 |

rr table

| experiment | protocol | test | request_size | response_size | metric | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | tcp | request and response | 64 | 64 | transactions per second | 10 |
| 5 | tcp | request and response | 64 | 64 | cpu utilization | .6 |
| 6 | tcp | request and response | 64 | 1024 | transactions per second | 8 |
| 6 | tcp | request and response | 64 | 1024 | cpu utilization | .5 |
| 7 | udp | request and response | 64 | 64 | transactions per second | 30 |
| 7 | udp | request and response | 64 | 64 | cpu utilization | .4 |
| 8 | udp | request and response | 64 | 1024 | transactions per second | 29 |
| 8 | udp | request and response | 64 | 64 | cpu utilization | .75 |

As of now, the outcomes for the experiments are the listed in the metric column, and their value is in the value column.

I know that I can drop the test specific columns like `stream_size`, `request_size`, and `response_size`, and then bind the rows to make one data frame.

Using R and tidyverse tools, how would you go about combining the two data frames into a long format, so that the combined data frame does not have the test specific columns, `stream_size`, `request_size`, and `response_size`?

Is there a better or more succinct way to make the schema for these experiments' data to facilitate combining the data frames?

Comment: Are you asking about Python code or about R code?

Comment: R at the moment because it facilitates my thinking best for these problems, but I'll probably have to rewrite it in python too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the 2 dataframes together, then pivot just the columns that end with `size` to long form.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(stream, rr) %>%
  pivot_longer(ends_with("size"), names_to = "test_specific", values_to = "size", values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
   experiment protocol test                 metric                  value test_specific  size
        <int> <chr>    <chr>                <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>         <int>
 1          1 tcp      stream               throughput Gbps          10   stream_size      64
 2          1 tcp      stream               cpu utilization           0.5 stream_size      64
 3          2 tcp      stream               throughput Gbps          40   stream_size      64
 4          2 tcp      stream               cpu utilization           0.9 stream_size      64
 5          3 udp      stream               throughput Gbps          20   stream_size      64
 6          3 udp      stream               cpu utilization           0.5 stream_size      64
 7          4 udp      stream               throughput Gbps          60   stream_size      64
 8          4 udp      stream               cpu utilization           0.8 stream_size      64
 9          5 tcp      request and response transactions per second  10   request_size     64
10          5 tcp      request and response transactions per second  10   response_size    64
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Yeah I think that is the way to go. The size of the data frame could explode if I add more test specific factors and factor levels.